# Word interop c# как разделить ячейку на строки

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, interop, office-interop

Прошу помощи!
Возникла необходимость заполнить таблицу в виде такого шаблона:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам шаблон выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для заполнения используется класс со свойствами с типом данных списка (разновидность, товары). В принципе это не особо важно. Так же можно заполнять из базы данных.

В самом приложении Word есть функция разделения ячейки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно заполнить такую таблицу? Если есть та же возможность разделения ячейки, как далее заполнить эти ячейки? Может есть возможность сразу добавить заполненные строки (не таблицу) в ячейку?

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста код, и расскажите, что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Я не могу найти функцию разделения одной ячейки на несколько ячеек. Ведь, если в программе есть такая возможность, значит есть соответствующая функция. Я думаю, что код тут излишен.

Comment: А функцию объединения найти можете? Может это функция является просто обратной к объединению? То есть разделить быть может можно только что-то ранее объединенное? То что на скриншоте ворда - это может быть не атомарная функция, а комплекс операций.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теперь я поняла, что нужно читать документацию...

Метод Split для класса Cell:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.cell.split?view=word-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Word_Cell_Split_System_Object__System_Object__